# Как сделать пагинацию в html таблице Magento?

Tags: magento, pagination

Делаю [по этому гайду](https://indiestechtips.wordpress.com/2012/11/10/magento-paging-in-custom-collection/) пагинацию для html таблицы:

Так выглядит мой блок `app/code/local/Developer/Vendor/Block/Customer.php`

```
<?php


class VitaliyDev_Vendor_Block_Customer extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $collectionProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array(
                'name',
                'price',
                'owner_id',
            ))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('owner_id', array(
                'id' => Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId(),
            ));
        $this->setCollection($collectionProducts);
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();

        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'custom.pager');
        $pager->setCollection($this->getCollection());
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getCollection()->load();
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildChildHtml('pager');
    }
}
```

Мой layout `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/developer_vendor.xml`

```
<developervendor_customer_index>
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
            <reference name="content">
                <block
                        type="developervendor/customer"
                        name="index.content"
                        template="developervendor_vendor/customer/index.phtml"
                />
            </reference>
    </developervendor_customer_index>
```

Темплейт    `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/developer_vendor/customer/index.phtml`

```
<div class="title_customer_products">
    <?php echo $this->__('Your products')?>
</div>
<?php $collection = $this->getCollection(); ?>
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml() ?>
<table class="customer-products data-table">
    <thead>
        <th><?php echo $this->__('Id Product')?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->__('Name Product')?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->__('Price Product')?></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ( $this->getCollection() as $product):?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $product->getId()?></td>
            <td><?php echo $product->getName()?></td>
            <td><?php echo $product->getPrice()?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml() ?>

<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('*/customer/add')?>">
    <button class="add_product_button button" type="submit">add product</button>
</form>
```

Результата нет ( Пагинация не появляется !

**Что я делаю не правильно ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что блок **"pager"** установлен в качестве непосредственного ребенка для блока `VitaliyDev_Vendor_Block_Customer`, однако в методе `VitaliyDev_Vendor_Block_Customer::getPagerHtml()` вы пытаетесь извлечь детский элемент блока **"pager"**.

Чтобы устранить проблему достаточно изменить метод `getChildChildHtml()` на `getChildHtml()`, кстати, в рассматриваемом вами гайде используется именно метод `getChildHtml()`.

Comment: Спасибо! Даже не заметил!